# Explainable AI solutions and packages in Python

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, classification, data-mining

I recently built a logistic regression for binary classification

While I understand that logistic regression is inherentlt interpretable, I am trying to use explainable AI solutions to understand the predictions. For that, I am trying to make a list of all XAI solutions and compare the results against each other.

As of now, these are below that I have identified

**XAI solutions**

a) SHAP

b) LIME

c) PFI

d) Dependencies plots

**Python packages implementations**

a) Explainerdashboard

b) ExplainX.ai

c) Shapash

Is there anything that you can add to the list?

Would really be useful for beginner like me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few which I am aware of are:

**Permutation importance**, the python package is this [ELI5](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html)

Lime, Shap, PDP, and dependency plots you have already covered.

To understand AI explainability I would highly suggest reading:

1. https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/working-paper/2019/machine-learning-explainability-in-finance-an-application-to-default-risk-analysis
2. Taking this course on Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/learn/machine-learning-explainability

Comment: Updated, thanks

Comment: Sure, should be done today eod

Comment: Thanks, here is the updated link - https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/107928/usefulness-of-intercept-in-layman-terms-eli5

Answer (score 2):

Without being fully aware of what you are trying to solve, see below some explainability packages and/or methodologies that I have found very useful in the past especially for DL and NLP tasks.

Packages:

- https://github.com/pair-code/lit
- https://github.com/mruberry/captum
- https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/what_if_tool

Writeups and papers:

- https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2019/file/567b8f5f423af15818a068235807edc0-Paper.pdf
- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.02479.pdf

Specific to tabular data,

I have found quite insightful to use the masks that are produce per step in the TabNet model. Tabnet also produces aggregated importance in the same context that Shap does. Masks can inform how these important features are getting combined in order to boost model performance.

You can easily experiment with this using the dreamquark-ai implementation in pure pytorch or fast.ai.

- TabNet paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.07442
- TabNet pytorch implementation: https://github.com/dreamquark-ai/tabnet
- TabNet fast ai: https://github.com/mgrankin/fast_tabnet

Hope this helps.

Edit: Tabnet

Comment: thanks, upvoted. useful suggestions. Do you know of anything more for tabular data? structured data analysis using classical machine learning algos?

Comment: Sure, for tabular data you can use the step-wise masks that are produced during training/inference with TabNet. I will update.